# MySQL connection throws null reference

Tags: c#, mysql, connection

My MySQL connection throws null reference although this code worked well one year ago.
The line where the debugger indicates the exception contains
"connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);":

```
DBConnect MySqlConnection = new DBConnect();

string[] resultArray = MySqlConnection.GetValidUser(
    "tbl_user",
    tbEmail.Text, 
    tbPassword.Text
);

//THROWS null reference exception in method 'private bool OpenConnection()'
//A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
```

This is my DBConnect class:

```
class DBConnect
{
    private MySqlConnection connection;
    private string server;
    private string database;
    private string uid;
    private string password;

    public DBConnect()
    {
        server = "x.x.x.x";
        database = "...";
        uid = "...";
        password = "...";

        string connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" +
                                  "DATABASE=" + database + ";" +
                                  "UID=" + uid + ";" +
                                  "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    private bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to MySQL server.");
                    break;

                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password.");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public string[] GetValidUser(string dbTable, string dbUsername, string dbPassword)
    {
        string query = "SELECT id,email,password FROM " + dbTable +
                       " WHERE email='" + dbUsername +
                       "' AND password='" + dbPassword + "'";

        string[] resultArray = new string[3];

        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                resultArray[0] = dataReader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                resultArray[1] = dataReader.GetString(1);
                resultArray[2] = dataReader.GetString(2);
            }

            dataReader.Close();
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
        return resultArray;
    }
}
```

The original code for the database class can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL).

Comment: Exactly which line throws this exception? Also: `using` statements! (try some)

Comment: Obligatory feedback, but: "you need to parameterize that SQL" and "stop storing passwords as plain text" (note: `dbTable` can't be parameterized, but should be white-listed or hard-coded instead)

Comment: @MarcGravell: overlooked it. However, the code is open for sql injection with using string concatenation to build the sql query. Instead use sql-parameters. Such classes often have issues like this or the difficulty to use  the `using`-statement to ensure that everything gets disposed and closed properly.

Comment: @Tim indeed; on this *one occasion*, this is even greater than that, since I could craft an attack that returned **someone else's** password to me, which is just - mind bogglingly bad, as in "we need to tell our users that they need to change all their passwords everywhere, because we've probably leaked them already, and have no clue/evidence that we have" - heck, I could probably steal all their passwords and email addresses with Havij based on that code

Comment: with your edit, there seems to be some confusion over whether the error is in the constructor (`DBConnect`) vs the method (`OpenConnection`) - can you clarify? Note that neither of those shows anything that *should* error; the first thing that leaps to mind is: try adding `readonly` to the connection field, i.e. `private readonly MySqlConnection connection` - this will highlight whether any code is setting the connection to `null`, by not compiling if it does that!

Comment: However - and I cannot emphasize this enough - the code shown is **jaw droppingly insecure**; we aren't griefing you for fun and giggles - we're trying to tell you that this code, no matter where used, is currently an active risk to both your organisation and your users. If you have *any* kind of "hey boss, I think we might have a problem here" process / channel: invoke it *now* - you really really have a major problem here. This "major problem" has nothing to do with the null-reference-exception, and will not go away by fixing the NRE.

Comment: Alright. I am now aware that the code is insecure. But the matter of fact is if I would know how to make it more secure and even running I would have done it.

Comment: @udgru k; tell you what - let's focus on the null-reference-exception for now; I'll happily put some notes together on the security aspect afterwards; have you tried adding the `readonly` ?

Comment: readonly will not be excepted because of the initialization: connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString); (Error 1 A readonly field cannot be assigned to (except in a constructor or a variable initializer)

Comment: But the statement is in the constructor. Please do a clean solution, and perform a full rebuild.

Comment: @udgru that **is** the constructor, so it should be accepted; if *another* line of code is trying to assign to the field, that could be part of the problem

Comment: The result is the error: "Das Format der Initialisierungszeichenfolge stimmt nicht mit der Spezifikation überein, die bei Index '81' beginnt."

Comment: While "connection = new MySqlConnection(); connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;" throws an exception the statement "connection = new MySqlConnection();" does not...

Comment: @udgru that sounds like your connection string is invalid, then; have you changed the database password lately, perhaps including obscure characters? Note that such characters need to be **encoded**; you can use `DbConnectionStringBuilder` to help with that (I'll do a sample)

Comment: The database user password contains special characters, yes.

Comment: @udgru k; try the code in my 2nd answer then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among other things, it sounds like you have problems with the connection string - from comments:

> While "connection = new MySqlConnection(); connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;" throws an exception the statement "connection = new MySqlConnection();" does not...

The difference here is simply: in the latter *you aren't setting the connection string* - so it sounds like your connection string is not correctly escaping the values (most likely, the password); you could try:

```
var cs = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
cs["SERVER"] = server;
cs["DATABASE"] = database;
cs["UID"] = uid;
cs["PASSWORD"] = password;
var connectionString = cs.ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 9):

This is not an answer to the `NullReferenceException` - we're still working through that in the comments; this is feedback for the security parts.

The first thing we can look at is SQL injection; this is very easy to fix - see below (note I've tidied some other things too)

```
// note: return could be "bool" or some kind of strongly-typed User object
// but I'm not going to change that here
public string[] GetValidUser(string dbUsername, string dbPassword)
{
    // no need for the table to be a parameter; the other two should
    // be treated as SQL parameters
    string query = @"
SELECT id,email,password FROM tbl_user
WHERE email=@email AND password=@password";

    string[] resultArray = new string[3];

    // note: it isn't clear what you expect to happen if the connection
    // doesn't open...
    if (this.OpenConnection())
    {
        try // try+finally ensures that we always close what we open
        {
            using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", dbUserName); 
                // I'll talk about this one later...
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", dbPassword); 

                using(MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dataReader.Read()) // no need for "while"
                                           // since only 1 row expected
                    {
                        // it would be nice to replace this with some kind of User
                        //  object with named properties to return, but...
                        resultArray[0] = dataReader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                        resultArray[1] = dataReader.GetString(1);
                        resultArray[2] = dataReader.GetString(2);

                        if(dataReader.Read())
                        { // that smells of trouble!
                            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                                "Unexpected duplicate user record!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```

Now, you might be thinking "that's too much code" - sure; and tools exist to help with that! For example, suppose we did:

```
public class User {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
    public string Password {get;set;} // I'll talk about this later
}
```

We can then use [dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) and LINQ to do all the heavy lifting for us:

```
public User GetValidUser(string email, string password) {
    return connection.Query<User>(@"
SELECT id,email,password FROM tbl_user
WHERE email=@email AND password=@password",
      new {email, password} // the parameters - names are implicit
    ).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

This does *everything* you have (including safely opening and closing the connection), but it does it cleanly and safely. If it method returns a `null` value for the `User`, it means no match was found. If a non-null `User` instance is returned - it should contain all the expected values just using name-based conventions (meaning: the property names and column names match).

You might notice that the only code that remains is *actually useful code* - it isn't boring plumbing. Tools like dapper *are your friend*; use them.

---

Finally; passwords. You should never store passwords. Ever. Not even once. Not even encrypted. Never. You should *only* store *hashes* of passwords. This means that you can never retrieve them. Instead, you should hash what the user supplies and compare it to the pre-existing hashed value; if the hashes match: that's a pass. This is a complicated area and will require significant changes, but you **should do this**. This is important. What you have at the moment is insecure.